# Is there a flight booking site that allows no specific destination?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, flight-search-engines

If I want to fly from departure location and return to departure location on specified date but no specific destination.

**Is there a flight booking site that allows no specific destination?**

Answer (score 3):

skyscanner.net

You specify your destination as "everywhere" and it gives you options to delve into.